# Incorrect Total in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

Ok I have to calculate in C this tax rate. Basically, the first 10,000 isn't taxed, the next 30,000 is taxed 10% and the next 20,000 is taxed 20%. So for example:
Your income is 60,000.
The first 10,000 isn't taxed, so now there is 50,000 remaining.
The next 30,000 of that 50,000 is taxed 10% so 3,000.
You now have 20,000 and the bracket states the next 20,000 is taxed 20% so 4,000. 
The total tax will equal 3,000 + 4,000 which 7,000. 
Now my code isn't coming up with the correct total. Mind you this is my first semester in C.

```
// Aundray Ortiz
// 2/22/15
// COP3223
// tax



int main(){
int income;
int total = 0;

printf("What is your income in dollars?\n");
scanf("%d", &income);

int for_free;
int next_bracket;

for_free = income - 10,0000;
next_bracket = for_free - 30,000;

if (for_free >= 0){
    total = for_free*.1;
}

if (next_bracket >= 0){
    total = total + (next_bracket*.2);

}

printf("You will pay %d in taxes.", total);






return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that I am not too familiar with C but I believe you are not suppose to use comas in numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why your code does not work is because you did not limit `for_free` to 30000.

Another is that there are syntax errors in `10,0000` and `30,000` (apart from the wrong value). You must remove the commas.

There is also a compiler warning due to doing a `double` calculation with `total = for_free*.1;` which (may) truncate the `double` value when it is written back to an `int` value.

Here is the code cleaned up, and a higher tax rate included.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOR_FREE    10000
#define LOW_BRACKET 30000
#define BIG_BRACKET 20000
#define LOW_RATE    0.10
#define HIGH_RATE   0.20
#define HUGE_RATE   0.50

int main(void) {
    int income = 0;
    int lowtaxable = 0, hightaxable = 0, hugetaxable = 0;
    double taxdue = 0;
    printf("What is your income in dollars?\n");
    scanf("%d", &income);

    lowtaxable = income - FOR_FREE;
    if (lowtaxable > LOW_BRACKET) {
        hightaxable = lowtaxable - LOW_BRACKET;
        lowtaxable = LOW_BRACKET;
    }
    if (hightaxable > BIG_BRACKET) {
        hugetaxable = hightaxable - BIG_BRACKET;
        hightaxable = BIG_BRACKET;
    }
    taxdue = LOW_RATE  * lowtaxable
           + HIGH_RATE * hightaxable
           + HUGE_RATE * hugetaxable;
    printf("You will pay %.2f in taxes.\n", taxdue);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One quick question, @Weather Vane, the highest tax rate is infinite so how would I set the parameters to that constant?
Like the chart I am working from looks like this:

0,10000 tax 0%
10,000, 40,000 tax 10%
40,000 to infinity tax 20%

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a higher tax rate. How does an infinite tax rate work? I would lie.

Comment: "Basically, what this means is that the first $10,000 of your income is not taxed, the next $30,000
of it is taxed at 10%, and if you have more income, the rest of it is taxed at 20%. For example, if
someone’s income is 20,000, they would pay no tax for the first $10,000 and $1,000 on the next
$10,000 they earned, for a total of $1,000 tax. If someone’s income is $60,000, then would pay
no tax for the first $10,000, $3,000 for the next $30,000 of income and $4,000 for the last
$20,000 of income for a total of $7,000 in tax." This is the description.

Comment: Your OP said *"the next 20,000 is taxed 20%"* which is why I have added a 50% tax rate from 60,000.

Comment: My apologies @Weather Vane for my terrible explanation. I was using his test case without citing that.

Comment: It's still a little off, I think what he wants is the first 100000 isn't taxed, the next 30,000, is taxed and the remainder left over is taxed 20%

Comment: Should be easy for you now.